# Converting a data URI back to SVG

Tags: svg, data-uri

Might be a silly question but is it possible to convert a data URI back to SVG? I've Googled & searched SO and found nothing on the subject, loads of stuff on the other way round of course.

Thanks!

Edit: sorry should've been more specific - a data:image like this:

`data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA4MCA4MCI+PHBhdGggZmlsbD0iIzFBMzc2MSIgZD0iTTE3Ljc4IDI1LjY1Yy44OS0uODkgMi4zNS0uODkgMy4yNSAwTDQwIDQ0LjU5bDE4Ljk3LTE4Ljk1Yy44OS0uODkgMi4zNS0uODkgMy4yNCAwbDIuNDMgMi40M2MuODkuODkuODkgMi4zNSAwIDMuMjVMNDEuNjIgNTQuMzVjLS45Ljg5LTIuMzUuODktMy4yNSAwTDE1LjM1IDMxLjMzYy0uODktLjg5LS44OS0yLjM1IDAtMy4yNWwyLjQzLTIuNDN6Ii8+PC9zdmc+`

Comment: In a web page in order to modify it or manually i.e. look at the application source and convert the appropriate bit by pasting into a conversion program?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am going to assume you mean a Base64 encoded data URI.

The answer is yes.  The URI will look something like:

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0c...
```

The Base64 part is the part that starts with `PH`. Copy that part into an online converter such as [this one](https://www.base64decode.org/).

Comment: I gave you a one up, but that link just doesn't convert the a simple shape uri like this: http://jointjs.com/rappid/docs/format/svg

Comment: on a side note, doesn't the encoded uri look malformed in IE with all those "%" in there?  Is a % symbol ever supposed to be in a base64 uri?

Comment: Whatt URI?  I don't see one at that link.

Comment: If you click on that link and scroll down to see the "open As SVG" button, it opens a new window with a solo <img> with the encoded uri with a bunch of "%" in there..but it still opens up in IE?

Answer (score 66):

1. View the data URI in a web browser
2. Use inspect element
3. Open the data URI in new browser window/tab
4. Save the image as an .svg file

Comment: Like this one, faster than the other answer (that also works fine), thanks!

Comment: Beautiful.  Definitely an easier way.

Comment: Note: step 3 means to right-click on the URI and choose "Open in new tab". Copy & paste to the URL bar will *not* work due to encoding issues. Chrome 76 here.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Firefox, but works in Chrome.

Comment: Starting a few days ago seems like Chrome stopped supporting this. Now when saving the file it just hangs.

Comment: Doesn't work in chrome or FF, just gives you the data URI in the omnibar

Answer (score 20):

Using javascript, you can open developer tool and run this code in the 
console:

```js
var dataURI = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA4MCA4MCI+PHBhdGggZmlsbD0iIzFBMzc2MSIgZD0iTTE3Ljc4IDI1LjY1Yy44OS0uODkgMi4zNS0uODkgMy4yNSAwTDQwIDQ0LjU5bDE4Ljk3LTE4Ljk1Yy44OS0uODkgMi4zNS0uODkgMy4yNCAwbDIuNDMgMi40M2MuODkuODkuODkgMi4zNSAwIDMuMjVMNDEuNjIgNTQuMzVjLS45Ljg5LTIuMzUuODktMy4yNSAwTDE1LjM1IDMxLjMzYy0uODktLjg5LS44OS0yLjM1IDAtMy4yNWwyLjQzLTIuNDN6Ii8+PC9zdmc+';

var svg = atob(dataURI.replace(/data:image\/svg\+xml;base64,/, ''));
console.log(svg);
```

The atob() method decodes a base-64 encoded string.

Comment: Getting this error: ```The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded```

Comment: @HidaytRahman you may have different MIme type of the data (you will need to update the regex) or it's not base64.

Comment: am struggling with svg single path with ```d``` attribute i want to make it multiple path so i can select each path to perfrom delete or color

Comment: @HidaytRahman that SVG is base64 encoded string? if not you should ask another question, it may be not related to the thing you think it's related (check [X/Y Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)).

Comment: this worked for me! that's what I was looking for! 10x dude

Answer (score -1):

**Check out this website [SVG VIEWER](https://www.svgviewer.dev/). You can put your .svg file or SVG Text-Based to this website. After that, you can download as .svg, .jsx, and .png extension.**